# Combine any numbers to get the target sum or total

Tags: vba

I have 2 columns. First contains 10,15,30,45,35,1,2,3,1000,,,and so on. The 2nd column contains 86,55,,,,and so on. The first combination should be 30,55 & 1 for 86, and the next result should be 10 & 45 for 55 . But I want to get their index instead of 30,55 & 1, Please help..(I have seen similar to this but in C# not in VBA. I want in excel VBA)

Comment: The hard part is figuring that it has to be 30, 55 and 1 specifically that add up to 86, not returning their indices instead of the values. Sounds like you have already done the figuring part?

Comment: Thanks for the response @GSerg, you got it and I still don't know how to figure it out. I can curtail the choices (though still not perfect criteria) to their corresponding date. The date of entries of the combinations are not greater than (or later than) the date of entry of their targetted sum. After considering the date, the code must prioritize the bigger value/s. For instance, in column 1, there is an instant 86, the safest solution is 86. Because other sums might need 46 & 40 individually, thus 86 is the safest for 86 sum.  I hope this gives more clarity.

Comment: That would be the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).